# How to stop solving after one solution is found?

Tags: equation-solving

```
With[{P = 12}, 
  Solve[{a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a + b + c == P, 0 < b <= a, c > 0}, {a, b, c}, Integers]]
```

> {{a -> 4, b -> 3, c -> 5}}

```
With[{P = 120},
  Solve[{a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a + b + c == P, 0 < b <= a, c > 0}, {a, b, c}, Integers]]
```

> {{a -> 40, b -> 30, c -> 50}, {a -> 45, b -> 24, c -> 51}, {a -> 48, 
>     b -> 20, c -> 52}}

My goal is to keep only solutions for P values such that the system has a unique solution.

For example, to find solutions for all `P < 1000`, I can run this 998 times, and count how many times I only gets a single solution. But this seems inefficient.

For `P = 120`, if the solver could be stopped immediately after the second solution was found, solving the problem would be much quicker.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to find? One solution for each perimeter value or the perimeters that allow only one solution ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry if this was not clear. I will edit my post.

Comment: Just in case [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

Comment: @belisarius See updates. I hope I have made myself clearer.

Comment: By the way are you working on [Project Euler #75](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=75), or just using this as an example?

Comment: Algos: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:C_sharp

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes! I did not want to reveal too much,which was not suppose to, I think.

Comment: Good luck!  Consider other directions of approach as well; 1.5 million applications of `FindInstance` is not going to fit in the "one minute rule."

Answer (score 4):

`FindInstance`, as described by Mr.Wizard, gives solutions for a given perimeter, which may then be tested for uniqueness. However, Project Euler challenges you to consider and learn about other methods which solve the problem, usually faster and without a mysterious "black box".

For example, this problem concerns right-angled triangles with integer sides, Pythagorean triangles. Search the web for such triangles to find the parametric representation for the sides $\{a,b,c\}$ of primitive triangles. What is the perimeter $a+b+c$ in terms of the two parameters $m$ and $n$? Each $\{m,n\}$ produces a primitive Pythagorean triangle whose perimeter may be scaled by 1,2,3,... up to the perimeter bound. Make a histogram of scaled triangle perimeters as you vary $\{m,n\}$, and pick those histogram elements with just a single entry.

Alternatively, research Diophantine equations. Combine $a^2+b^2=c^2$ with perimeter $p=a+b+c$ to write $a^2+b^2=(p-a-b)^2$, an equation in two integer unknowns, given perimeter $p$. Can you factor this equation into something like $u*v=p^2/2$? Then conditions for a unique solution are available in terms of the divisors of $p^2/2$.

Researching these techniques helps solve this and many other PE problems.

Answer (score 2):

Though there may be an analytic approach to your problem I think for the generic case you can still make use of [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html); request two solutions and see how many it returns (zero, one, two).

```
FindInstance[
  {a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a + b + c == 1200, 0 < b <= a, c > 0},
  {a, b, c}, Integers, 2
]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 450, b -> 240, c -> 510}, {a -> 560, b -> 75, c -> 565}}
> ```

This should not waste time finding the third or greater solution, as you requested.

A test:

```
solve = FindInstance[{a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a + b + c == #, 0 < b <= a, c > 0}, {a, b, c}, 
    Integers, 2] &;

Select[Range@100, Length @ solve[#] == 1 &]
```

> ```
> {12, 24, 30, 36, 40, 48, 56, 70, 72, 80, 96}
> ```

Comment: Sorry. I feel that there may still be some confusion. Basically, I would disregard this P=1200. I want a "message" from MMA, telling me there is more than one solution. The message could just be `False`. I dont even need to see any solution.

Comment: @Chen your comment appears to have been cut off.

Comment: Sorry, thats wha happens when you have more than one input methods on the keyboard and the enter key is a switch between Chinese and English.

Comment: @Chen Okay, whether you need to see a solution or not can you not use the method above?  Just check if the length of the output of `FindInstance` equals 1?

Comment: I believe I have misunderstood the use of `FindInstance`! This seems a stupid question now. I knew `FindInstance, but I thought if I ask for 2 solutions, it will try to find two and not give just one....

Comment: @Chen These things are not always clear.  If they were this site probably wouldn't even be here; we'd all just read The Mathematica Book and be transformed into faultless *Mathematica* masters. ;^)

Comment: Just for information, I am testing all P<1500000, which is still not efficient enough. So I will do some more digging on algorithms and backgrounds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26164/discussion-between-chen-stats-yu-and-mr-wizard).

Comment: Based on some quick testing this is actually a tad slower than simply using `Solve`. (Even running the test on a case with lots of solutions (1499904) there is no savings. )

Comment: btw anybody know what `P` give the most results? (I encountered several with 26 soluitons, but estimate a couple of weeks to brute force it. )

Comment: @george2079 1441440 with 124 solutions, found in about four seconds on my machine.  As already hinted at (or perhaps a bit more) by Kenny there is another way to approach this.

Comment: `FindInstance` takes 1 - 2 seconds per solution for me. Guess its time for a faster machine!

Comment: @george2079 Time for a faster approach. ;-)

Comment: @george2079 The first occurrence of 150 solutions is at perimeter p=6224400, while 200 solutions first appears at p=12113640, and 330 solutions at p=24504480. Calculations up to p of 25 million took 10 s. But I still want a faster machine...